# Nesting xgboost in mclapply while still using OpenMP for parallel processing in Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to run a function in multiple instances at once (using shared memory), so I am using mclapply as follows:

```
library(caret)
library(plyr)
library(xgboost)
library(doMC)
library(parallel)

foo <- function(df) {
  set.seed(2)
  mod <- train(Class ~ ., data = df, 
               method = "xgbTree", tuneLength = 50,
               trControl = trainControl(search = "random"))
  invisible(mod)
}

set.seed(1)
dat1 <- twoClassSim(1000)
dat2 <- twoClassSim(1001)
dat3 <- twoClassSim(1002)
dat4 <- twoClassSim(1003)

list <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4)

mclapply(list, foo, mc.cores = 2)
```

I have a 16 core machine. When I do this, it spawns two processes, both running at 100% CPU usage. However, if I just ran

```
lapply(list, foo)
```

It would spawn 1 process running at 1600% (OpenMP is working).

How can I get it to run two processes, both at 800% CPU usage? I have tried doing 
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
but it doesn't seem to work.

Please advise.

Thanks!

EDIT: I set nthread = 8 in the train function, and OpenMP seems to work, but it does not speed anything up at all. Doing registerDoMC(8) before anything makes it speed up by 3x, but then it uses up 8 times the memory, making me run out of memory. Any ideas?